# How in Ansible Tower / AWX can I upload a files from another git repository to a role (/files)?

Tags: git, ansible, git-submodules, ansible-awx

tried 2 ways:

- use submodules, but how do I do checkout?
- use git module ansible, but credentials for Source Control and Machine this is a different access. And user for ssh Machine does not have access to the git repository.

Comment: Why do you need to put in role's file directory ? Simply put it in the files directory adjacent to your playbook.

Comment: because files are edited in a different git repository. and I need to get the latest version of them.

Comment: You can create a role which only contains the files in this case. But your use case looks really weird...

Comment: for example, I need to install and copy the configuration for the app, and the configuration itself is located in the app's git repository

Comment: Why would you want to copy that inside a role then ? Put that info in your project using the role, or in your inventory. As a very generic entry point to the subject: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html

Answer (score 0):

For this, we use curl (on pipeline)

```
curl --header "your's authent" -s -o "named_file" "https://your's_git/path_of_file/raw"
```

with ansible, you can use get_url
source  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html